# Two.JS Point on Curve

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, curve, two.js

I have a Two.JS Polygon Object.
Now I want the x/y position of a point (the point's position is given on the curve in %)

A Two.JS Polygon has the property ending. You can give a number between 0 and 1 there.
Thats what I want for a particular point.
Is there a way to get the x/y of a point ON the curve?

Maybe it's possible with another JS Canvas/SVG Lib.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Suppose that vertices is your Two.Vector with which you construct the polygon, and pos is the position in %. Then you get the vertex and its position by

```
var i = round((pos * vertices.length)/100);
var v = vertices[i];
console.log(v.x, v.y);
```

Now this gives you a vertex, and pos is the relative **index position**.

If you want to have the point on the curve which lies exactly pos% of **curve length** away from the beginning, that's harder.

Comment: This answer follows the same paradigm as the `beginning` and `ending` properties in two.js. If you're interested in actually interpolating between the points I'd recommend checking tween.js: http://sole.github.io/tween.js/examples/06_array_interpolation.html